# Read dark mode schedule programmatically

Tags: ios, darkmode

I have such use case that requires me to know ahead of time whether dark mode will be enabled in time X in the future, because I am pushing a notification with an image as attachment, and the looks and feels of the image is drastically different when dark mode is toggled on.

As a result I wonder if I can read device's dark mode schedule and (if best) detect the change of the schedule, so I can choose the different notification attachment that blends better into the theme.

There are various existing answers of **detecting (changes of) dark mode in the current moment**, which is not what I want.

Comment: Might be better to just attach a transparent PNG or something. Not everyone has scheduled dark mode (for example I sometimes turn it on and sometimes turn it off, no reason really)

Comment: @aheze This is the first option I tried, but the colors themes are different. For example, the primary label color is black under light mode but black under dark mode.

Comment: Ah. Then maybe a transparent gray? But anyway I'm pretty sure there's now way to read when dark mode is scheduled...

Comment: You could potentially use a UNNotificationServiceExtension to load a specific image variant. This would at least show a matching image if the user views the notification immediately https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the schedule, as @aheze pointed out in comments. However, for your purposes, you don't need to.

Instead, find the image in your Assets.xcassets folder and select Any, Dark or Any, Light, Dark like this.

[image]

After this, you will notice that you have 3 image types templates, you can just drag in the appropriate images now and the right one will be shown depending on whether the device is in light mode or dark mode.